# Prevent multiple instances of Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I'd like to make an RCP application that only opens once.

If you open it again, it focuses (ideally passing through the arguments supplied) on the original window.

My use-case involves multiple concurrent users (with their own user accounts) on the same computer, so I don't think the route of opening a port would work.

I'm using RCP4 - a lot of the existing stuff I've seen online is RCP3 or older.

Comment: By 'concurrent' do you mean several displays connected to the computer? SWT isn't designed for that set up and won't work.

Comment: by concurrent, I mean a computer being used by multiple users simultaneously - a server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a library available here: http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/

The JUnique library can be used to prevent a user to run at the same time more instances of the same Java application.

An example of how it is used here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String appId = "myapplicationid";
    boolean alreadyRunning;
    try {
        JUnique.acquireLock(appId);
        alreadyRunning = false;
    } catch (AlreadyLockedException e) {
        alreadyRunning = true;
    }
    if (!alreadyRunning) {
        // Start sequence here
    }
}
```